# How to successfully run node server with IIS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, port, reverse-proxy, iis-10

So I have a web application with `ISS-10`, running on `wwww.mymindmapper.com` and listening on `port:80`. I have two simple pages (`login.html` & `register.html`). Here is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLLfU.jpg

My main objective is to try and figure out how to create a Node JS server (`port: 81`) with my webApp on IIS that is on `port: 80`. Here is my `app.js` file:

```
//USE `nodemon scripts/server.js` on Terminal to refresh Node Server on File Save.
//USE 'pm2 start scripts/server.js' on Terminal to start pm2 for IIS ??????????????????

//Import Node JS modules
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan"); 
const mysql = require("mysql");

//Create a new instance of express()
const app = express();

//GET INFORMATION ABOUT THE SERVER REQUESTS (OS, Browser, time, Internal Errors, Status Codes)
app.use(morgan('short')); //'short', 'combined'

//Require files from folder public     (THIS CONTAINS ALL .html files inc. login.html and register.html)
app.use(express.static('./public'));

//Listen on PORT:80 with a callback function
app.listen(81, ()=>{
    console.log("Server running on port 81");
});
```

Please note that when i make requests through terminal on Visual Studio Code, everything works as expected. Data can be added/deleted from my database. (I use `XAMPP` - Apache listens on `port:80` and mMySQL listens on `port:3306`).

I have read somewhere that this can be solved with a `Reverse Proxy` on IIS. However this doesn't seems to work. Also when the reverse-proxy configuration is made the following error occurs when i refresh the page.

[image: Reverse proxy configuration]

[image]

Comment: I have one site running NodeJS on IIS and we use IIS Node to manage it: https://github.com/Azure/iisnode I didn't setup the site, so I'm not 100% on the config.

Comment: At various points in this question you've claimed that IIS is running on port 80 and Apache is running on port 80. Which is it? Are you dealing with multiple computers? Did you run your Node application on both of them?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno, thanks. I will have a look.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your reply. No, just one computer. I'm not sure how this works. When i go to `localhost:80` the XAMPP welcome page loads, and when I try `mymindmapper.com` it loads my webApplication. This can also work simultaneously.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno I just checked the modules on my WebApp in IIS, and `iisnode` does NOT exists. Is this something I want to include?

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou Try it on a dev or test server. You should be able to run the server without the reverse proxy approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy, there is no need to set up the outbound rules. the above settings you wrote is enough to forward the IIS requests to node server.
[image]
In Application Request Routing, enable proxy functionality.
[image]
**Index.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('Hello World');
})
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!");
})
```

My IIS site bindings.
[image]
Result.
[image]
Adding the Reverse Proxy Rules generates a `webconfig` file with below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Besides, if you have created a server farm in the `server farms`, please remove it or add the local IP as the default server. Otherwise, there will be an error that cannot connect to the server.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I found out that Application Request Routing 3.0 extension wasn't installed, so I have fixed that. I have changed my app.js to listen on `port:3000`, and created a new reverse proxy without inbounds (I have deleted the other 2). When I installed Application Request Routing the proxy functionality was already enabled, and changed the bindings to ALL UNASIGNED, and it worked perfectly. YOU ARE A GOD my friend. :D