# How to deploy React.js with Node backend in IIS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis

I have an application built with Create React App that I want to use Node.js as a backend to load data from a database.  Basically, I want Node to load the data and then use Create React App to do stuff with it.  To do so I used this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0/.  I have set up a working development environment where I have all the Create React App in a client folder, a server.js that loads the data (from MS SQL Server if that's relevant), and a proxy set in client/package.json (CRA's package.json) for the port that the node app is running on (5000 in my case).  I then run yarn dev and these two servers run together and talk to each other and everything works great.

The issue is deploying.  My organization uses IIS.  From what I can gather Node and IIS are not the ideal combination but IIS is what we use for everything.  I would like the server.js and the CRA to be in the same folder and to basically function like one app as much as possible (I know that Node will need to run its own server).  I would also like a setup that can be easily changed or moved to another machine. What I've done thus far is:

1. Set up a single application with a client folder, which is the build for CRA, and then server.js in the root
2. In my react code, made API calls to http://localhost:5000 (in the development environment I could do fetch('api/somestuff') but to make it work in production I needed to do fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/somestuff') )
3. Installed pm2 and used it to run server.js and start the Node server

This worked, however I'm wondering whether this is the optimal way to do things.  This worked on my local machine but I don't know what will happen when I put it on our production machines.  Will the Node server block other applications?  Will it stay running no matter what or might it crash?  Ultimately this is going to be deployed in a multi-server environment where we have 2 load-balanced servers with identical code that are put through an F5 to form a single URL--will this impact anything?

I'm pretty new to programming so bear with me, I'm sorry if this question was confusingly phrased.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve NodeJS application from Windows Server Edition OS without using iisnode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450658/how-to-serve-nodejs-application-from-windows-server-edition-os-without-using-iis)

Comment: I tried this but had trouble getting my website to redirect my api requests, I wanted requests to  /api/somestuff to go to localhost:5000/api/somestuff but it kept looking in localhost/api/somestuff.  I created a rule that matches the pattern ^(api.*) and has rewrite URL http://localhost:5000/{R:0} but that didn't work, I also tried several other versions of this.

Comment: You can learn how to debug rules first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install ARR to work with IIS as a reverse proxy, which can forward the HTTP request to the backend NodeJS server.
Besides, for cross-domain request forwarding in the rewrite action type, we need to install `Application Request Routing`, and enable the proxy functionality.
[image]
[image]

Here are two examples of applying this feature, please check it.
[How to successfully run node server with IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391237/how-to-successfully-run-node-server-with-iis/62404191#62404191)
[ASP.net URL Rewrite subdirectory to external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330947/asp-net-url-rewrite-subdirectory-to-external-url/62341534#62341534)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.